# Bootstrap Responsive Collapsed Submenu has fixed height on first collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

This problem can be exhibited in all (that I know of) Twitter Bootstrap versions. So, I have a navbar and when the screen is smaller, it becomes a collapsable tray. This behaviour can be seen on the bootstrap demo site. I also have submenus, which appear collapsed on the initial navbar expansion. The problem is, on the first collapse, the collapsable gets an explicit height set. If you close and expand again, the collapsable gets a `height:auto;`

So, when I click a submenu item, the dropdown is expanded, but it overflows due to the height being explicitly set.

My attempted solution was adding:

```
$(function() {
  $('.nav-collapse').on({
    shown: function() {
      $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    },

    hidden: function() {
      $(this).css('height', '0px');
    }
  });
});
```

This doesn't seem to affect it at all, I've deleted that code and it still has the same effect. If a JS Fiddle would help, I'd be happy to provide one, but you can see all of this on the Bootstrap demo site.

Thanks in advance,
Charles.

Comment: You should provide a link to your demo site or a JS Fiddle. It's hard to understand your issue here. We use bootstrap extensively and haven't had any problems with overflows.

Comment: @Mauricio http://jsfiddle.net/nczJF/ - Click the tray, then try a dropdown menu, then close the tray and try again, and it should expand as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It bothered me a little, and after some searching, I found that the problem can be solved by adding the `.collapse` class to the `.nav-collapse` element.

[Working demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nczJF/52/)

One of those time when we just say *Meh.. I should have followed the doc to the letter* (see [`Responsive navbar`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)):

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
</div>
```

---

For posterity :

Found out thanks to this issue : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3788

I'm not sure if it really is related, but my debugging showed the problem on the first transition height resetting anyway ([source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/js/bootstrap-collapse.js#L70)) :

```
$.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is setting the element style height to 280px on initialization of the collapse element.

I added this JQuery line in my ready() function right after my call to .collapse()

```
$("#avail_detail").collapse();
$("#avail_detail").css("height","auto");
```

And, now things behave as I expect.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I added that code, but the collapse is being set up through unobtrusive data-toggle="collapse" and data-target=".nav-collapse" and it doesn't seem to fix it. You're totally right on the problem though, any chance you could amend this JsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/nczJF/

Comment: Overall, I've had better luck in Bootstrap being more explicit and using JavaScript directly, rather than using the markup methods.  This is the 2nd time I've circumnavigated a bug in Bootstrap via direct JavaScript.  That said, I'd still be interested in a markup solution to the problem.