# Wordpress Bootstrap theme responsive dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the bootstrap wordpress theme, but the dropdown menus don't display properly when in responsive mode.

If you open the menu, click the parent then close the menu and open it again It'll work, but it never works first time. Driving me crazy. Here is the link to the live code http://kylegoslan.co.uk

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: yeah...I know it's annoying I can't be more specific, but I just cant figure out why its not working as expected...especially as it works after you click the link then close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on this page is in fact correct. 
[Bootstrap Responsive Collapsed Submenu has fixed height on first collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735747/bootstrap-responsive-collapsed-submenu-has-fixed-height-on-first-collapse)

For me it was as simple as adding the "collapse" class to the div.

So the div thats...

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

should be...

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

simple as that :)

Answer (score 3):

On first nav toggle click, the height on `.nav-collapse` is set inline with JS to `style="height: 128px;"`, and it doesn't change when those nested child links are clicked. On the following toggle, after closing and reopening, that inline style is changed to `style="height: auto;"`, and this is the styling that seems to work. Has the bootstrap code been altered in any way that could cause this? It seems your issue would be resolved by explicitly setting `style="height: auto;"` on `.nav-collapse` (either in the CSS or onclick with jQuery), though I tend to imagine the bootstrap code should already be handling this. There be may some slight problem in the implementation...

Something like this for the jQuery route:

```
$('.collapsed').click(function() {
    $('.nav-collapse').height('auto');
});
```

In regards to CSS, a class name is inserted onto that expanded nav div that you should be able to target: `.in`. You could try something like this:

```
.in { height: auto; }
```

If you get really desperate (though this isn't recommended), you could couple that CSS with:

```
.in { height: auto !important; }
```

But it's certainly preferable to find and isolate your fix without such overrides. Best of luck.

Comment: It seems to be the same even when using the bootstrap theme straight from download. Thanks for your reply, I'll have a look at this at this when I get the chance and hand over the bounty :)

Comment: Interesting, some kind of bug I guess. Give me a shout if my suggestions don't pan out, glad to take another look :)

Comment: Found the answer, finally. You pointed me in the right direction. The answer to this post in indeed correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735747/bootstrap-responsive-collapsed-submenu-has-fixed-height-on-first-collapse 

So yeah, looks like a bug with the framework. Very surprised its not been fixed. But thanks for taking a look, I'll head over that bounty all the best. :)

Comment: Nice! I'll keep this in mind should I get into bootstrap myself. Interesting question and glad to know about the solution.